# LaTeX Warning: Citation `foo' on page N undefined on input line XX

Tags: bibtex

When I compile my tex document, I receive some warnings on all bib entries. The warning is

```
 LaTeX Warning: Citation `foo' on page N undefined on input line XX.
```

The commands I use are

```
 bibtex template.tex
 I couldn't open file name `template.tex.aux'

 pdflatex template.tex
 ....
 LaTeX Warning: Citation `foo' on page N undefined on input line XX.
```

The document is

```
documentclass[pageno]{jpaper}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\title{the tile}

\date{}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
the abs
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
 ....
\bstctlcite{bstctl:etal, bstctl:nodash, bstctl:simpurl}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranS}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

And the `reference.bib` file is

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{bstctl:etal,
  CTLuse_forced_etal = {no},
  CTLmax_names_forced_etal = {3},
}

@IEEEtranBSTCTL{bstctl:nodash,
  CTLdash_repeated_names = {no},
}

@IEEEtranBSTCTL{bstctl:simpurl,
  CTLname_url_prefix = {Available: },
}


@inproceedings{foo,
  author = "some ones",
  title = "{something}",
  booktitle = {proc},
  year = {2011},
  pages = {1-2},
}
 ....
```

What does the warning mean?

Comment: you need to run bibtex to generate the references

Comment: @David Carlisle: No I don't see any ?? in the pdf. The reference numbers are set correctly. Let me update the post with the commands

Comment: See the updated post

Comment: It is the same issue, you would have ? if you had any \cite commands, presumably \bstctlcite is a version of \nocite which adds entries to the bibliography without a in-text citation

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`bibtex template.tex` will never work.

you first need to run latex on `template.tex`, then just `bibtex template` and bibtex will look for `template.aux`.

when you again run latex (it has to be run twice), the citation references should be
available.

Comment: Yes they are gone after the third run of pdflatex

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain a bit more on that, please. Why it needs 2 runs to make the reference appear? It's kinda redundant?

Comment: @Catbuilts -- I recommend reading the linked duplicate question ([Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)), in particular item 3 under "How does this all work".  Sometimes (maybe even often) a second run isn't needed, but to be sure, it's usually necessary to consult the log file.  It's easier to just rerun.